# How to pass data via props.location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried to get a generic page to which I send data via links.

```
<NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" 
   to={
   {pathname:"/PageInfo-data" ,
    aboutProps:{
      title:"page info title"
    }
    }} 
>PageInfo data</NavLink>
```

and when I go to the component and call props.location, I get the state as undefined and can't access `aboutProps`

```
export default class PageInfo extends Component{

    render(){
        const About=(props)=>{
            console.log(props.location)
            return <div></div>
        }
        console.log(this.props.location)
        return <div></div>
    }

}
```

EDIT: I Found out the thing works, but i imperatively need to click the link, is there a way to make it that routing to the page directly makes it click the link? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The router will provide you with a location object in a few places:

```
Route component as this.props.location
Route render as ({ location }) => ()
Route children as ({ location }) => ()
withRouter as this.props.location
```

[withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)